# Replace data text with components in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm looking to generate popover highlight tags on data that I've gotten from a query. Currently, I've tried finding substrings wrapped in curly braces within the text, then replacing them with components, but I can't figure out how to get Vue to render & mount the new components

Example text:

```markdown
Lorem {ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetur {adipiscing} elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
```

I've created a fairly simple regex to find and grab text wrapped in curly braces:

```
\{(.[^{}]*)\}
```

And this is the code I've tried so far:

```
<template>
  <span v-html="paragraphText"></span>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import {MyComponent} from '#components';

export default defineComponent({
  data () {
    return {
      paragraphText: '',
    }
  },

  created () {
    const re = /\{(.[^{}]*)\}/g;
    let newText = `${this.text}`;
    let match: RegExpExecArray;

    do {
      match = re.exec(newText);
      if (match) {
        newText = newText.replace(
          match[0],
          `<MyComponent ref='${match[1]}' style='font-weight:bold;'>${match[1]}</MyComponent>`
        );
      }
    } while (match);
    
    this.paragraphText = newText;
  },

  components: {
    MyComponent,
  }
})
</script>
```

I'm well aware that `v-html` won't render components to avoid XSS attacks, but this is mostly just to show what I'm trying to achieve.

My reasoning behind having a component behind each one, is that I want the component to make a web request on hover, to grab some additional information about the word being highlighted.

I'm looking for the cleanest and/or most efficient solution possible - it doesn't have to be Options API

Comment: This is likely XY problem. Consider reasking with your case being explained. Depending on why this data has to be passed as a string, you may want to reconsider this. v-html is for html, as the name implies. It can't render components. You'd need runtime template compiler to make it work, which is an exotic case

Comment: @EstusFlask I've explained my case at the top of my post - I want to render popovers on text content grabbed in an ajax request. Perhaps this way that I'm trying to go about it with isn't the simplest, but to me it seems that this method would lead to the cleanest code and compiled html?

Comment: It wasn't explained enough. If this is plain HTML that is received from back end, you don't need to render components inside it, it can be handled with v-html as is.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes, but as I explained further down I'm not recieving plain HTML from the backend, I'm receiving text - so I'm trying to find a solution that handles rendering it on the frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is *clean* but it should do what you require - sorry, composition API, but it's so simple its trivial to convert to Options API

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue;

createApp({
    setup() {
        const data = ref("Lorem {ipsum} dolor sit amet, consectetur {adipiscing} elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt");
        const magic = computed(() => data.value.split('}').map(v => v.split('{')));
        return { data, magic };
    }
}).mount('#app');
```

```css
.this.would.be.your.component.rather.than.a.span {
  background-color :#ffdddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  <span v-for="([text, tag], i) in magic" :key="i">
    <span v-if="text.length">{{ text }}</span>
    <span class="this would be your component rather than a span" v-if="tag?.length" :title="`this is tag: ${tag}`">{{ tag }}</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

v-html interprets text as raw html, without doing any data binding, meaning it doesn't create any components. Maybe you want [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) instead?

On the topic at hand, if you want to highlight some matched text, I did it this way by using a mark html tag

```js
const highlightText = (word: string, search: RegExp): string => {
  return word.replace(search, function (matchedText) {
    return '<mark class="highlight">' + matchedText + '</mark>';
  });
};
```

And in template, I used v-html on object's field.

```html
<span v-if="isHighlighted" v-html="object.text"></span>
<span v-else>{{ object.text }}</span>
```

Now, in your case, you could go over your text, create a new object for each word with a boolean flag that indicates whether the word should be highlighted or not, and based on that iterate through that list with v-for directive, if it should be highlighted, use MyComponent otherwise use a span.

```html
<div v-for="(word, index) in words" :key="index">
    <MyComponent v-if="word.isHighlighted" :data="word.text" />
    <span v-else>{{ word.text }}</span>
</div>
```

---

Resources:

- https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html
- https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components