# Inserting components into the body of an article on Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Website on `Nuxt 3` and `Vue`. There was a need to insert components into the html of the article with the replacement of special tags. For example, if the `#GALLERY#` tag is present in the text of the article, then the `<v-gallery/>` component is embedded in its place. Or, if necessary, I can store the code of the `<v-gallery/>` component in the text of the article at once. But how do I get `Vue` to recognize it as a component?

Example:

```
<p>...</p>

#GALLERY_1#

<p>...</p>

#GALLERY_2#
```

I need to bypass all html and replace all occurrences of certain tags with their corresponding components. Or, I can immediately display the text of components in the markup:

```
<p>...</p>

<v-gallery :id="1"/>

<p>...</p>

<v-gallery :id="2"/>
```

But we need to somehow force `Vue` to connect components when it sees such markup.

---

In one of the examples I was sent, it is proposed to convert the text into an array using a special separator (in my example, this is the `#` symbol). I managed to do this. But now the next question has appeared - what to do with nested tags. If my special tag is displayed inside another tag, the browser will close this tag before it outputs the component that should be inside it.

Here is an example:

```
<article>
  <section>
    #GALLERY#
  </section>
</article>
```

Such markup is converted by the browser into such:

```
<article>
  <section>  
  </section>
</article>
<v-gallery/>
```

This will happen because the browser will get a piece of my code (up to `#GALLERY#`) as a completed text in `v-html` and will automatically close all tags in it. As a result, the markup will be incorrect. Are there any ways to avoid this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace data text with components in Vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74228654/replace-data-text-with-components-in-vue-3)

Comment: @MoritzRingler It looks like what I need, thank you! I was also offered to use web components for this task. Will it be more effective? If so, are there any examples?

Comment: @MoritzRingler Yes, everything is clear now, thank you. Indeed, it would be redundant.

Comment: @MoritzRingler I edited the question. Please look at the changes - I noticed a new problem in the method you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I said before was plain wrong, you can use [custom elements](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) pretty easily for this. Note however that custom elements are registered globally, so you have to be careful with names.

The idea is to replace occurrences of the identifiers, like `#GALLERY_1#` with a tag like `<my-gallery id="1"></my-gallery id="1">`, which Vue cannot resolve in `v-html`, but when they are registered in [`customElements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/customElements), the browser will resolve them using Vue micro-apps:

```js
const inputFragment = `
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 4px;">
    <i style="color: red;">#GALLERY_1#</i>
    <i style="color: blue;">#ELEMENT_35#</i>
    <i style="color: purple;">#GALLERY_2#</i>
  </div>
`

const vueComponent = {
  props: ['id', 'name'],
  template: `<slot>[{{name}} with id {{id}}]</slot>`
}

customElements.define('my-gallery', Vue.defineCustomElement({
  props: ['id'],
  components: {vueComponent},
  template: `<vueComponent name="gallery" :id="id"/>`
}))

customElements.define('my-element', Vue.defineCustomElement({
  props: ['id'],
  components: {vueComponent},
  template: `<vueComponent name="element" :id="id"/>`,
}))

const regex = /#([A-Z]+)_(\d+)#/g // a hash, an uppercased word, an underscore, a number, a hash
const replacer = (_, tagIdentifer, id) => {
  const tagName = 'my-' + tagIdentifer.toLowerCase()
  return `<${tagName} id="${id}"></${tagName}>`
}

const App = {
  template: `<pre>{{fragment}}</pre> becomes <div v-html="htmlData"/>`,
  setup(){
    const fragment = Vue.ref(inputFragment)
    return {
      fragment,
      htmlData: Vue.computed(() => fragment.value.replace(regex, replacer))
    }
  }
}
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, you could include the Vue template compiler in your build (as [the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/tooling.html#note-on-in-browser-template-compilation) say, you need to set an alias for vue [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74305016/4883195)). This increases the size of your build, but then you can compile and render the templates directly.

The idea here is again to replace the tag identifier as above, but this time, run the result through `Vue.compile()`, which gives you a render function that can be returned from a component's `render()` function:

```js
const inputFragment = `
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 4px;">
    <i style="color: red;">#GALLERY_1#</i>
    <i style="color: blue;">#GALLERY_2#</i>
  </div>
`

const myGallery = {
  props: ['id', 'name'],
  template: `<slot>[{{name}} with id {{id}}]</slot>`
}

const regex = /#([A-Z]+)_(\d+)#/g // a hash, an uppercased word, an underscore, a number, a hash
const replacer = (_, tagIdentifer, id) => {
  const tagId = tagIdentifer.toLowerCase()
  const tagName = 'my-' + tagId
  return `<${tagName} name="${tagId}" id="${id}"></${tagName}>`
}

const App = {
  components: {myGallery},
  render(ctx){
    const htmlData = inputFragment.replace(regex, replacer)
    const compiledTemplate = Vue.compile(htmlData)
    return compiledTemplate(ctx)
  }
}
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: It remains only to teach `Nuxt 3` how to work with web components.

Comment: Is there a way to convert a regular Vue component into a web component so that it can be used both as a regular and as a web?

Comment: You actually pass regular Vue components to `defineCustomElement()`, so you can use the Vue component directly. Not sure if it is good practice to register the Vue component as custom component under the same name, but I think it works as expected, i.e. Vue resolving it to the Vue component.

Comment: I managed to add a web component to Nuxt and it really solves my problem. Can you tell me if web components can use Nuxt plugins? I can't find any information about this.

Comment: The web component is just a front for a Vue component running with the same app configuration as the regular app, so I don't see why it wouldn't work. Btw. if the answer helped you, please consider leaving an upvote and/or marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: That's great! I'm happy. Let me know if you run into further issues

Comment: But as for `web components`, I noticed that, for example, the `$route` variable is not available in them. Maybe it's because the `$route` variable only works on the server side. However, if it is necessary to get the name of the current `layout` in the `web component`, then I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you can register plugins like router by [extending defineCustomElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808113/how-to-use-vue-router-and-vuex-inside-custom-element-from-root). Switching to the approach using Vue compiler might be less hassle though...

Comment: > Switching to the approach using Vue compiler might be less hassle though... 

Does it work in Nuxt? Could you clarify what you are talking about?

Comment: It's the second approach in the answer, where you use a Vue library that includes the template compiler, so you can compile templates directly. The advantage here is that you stay within the same app. Depending on your Nuxt version, there might be a flag available or you need to install a plugin (for info on both, check the [plugin page](https://github.com/huang-julien/nuxt-runtime-compiler). There is a manual way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65262705/4883195) which also has a nice explanation.